# Объясните, пожалуйста, зачем люди в js используют подобные конструкции и насколько это полезно/разумно?

Tags: javascript

Там, где return:

```
const orders = await apiQueueService.executeInQueue(this.api.futuresOpenOrders) || []
return orders && Array.isArray(orders) && orders.map((o) => ({ ...o, orderId: String(o.orderId) })) || []
```

Как по мне, проверка на то, что orders - это undefined или что orders - это не массив - лишние. Часто ли такое используют?

Comment: Перед return новая строка

Comment: проверка на массив нужна, чтобы следующий `map` не упал

Comment: @Grundy, так нефиг с апи мусор вместо массива возвращать.

Comment: @Grundy, а map всё равно упадёт когда внутри массива будет null.

Comment: @Qwertiy, про внутри массива я ничего не говорил :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут половина кода - мусор.

```
const orders = await apiQueueService.executeInQueue(this.api.futuresOpenOrders) || []
//                                                                              ^^^^^
```

В orders после такого никак не может быть ложного значения.

И даже если эту замену выкинуть, то

```
return orders && Array.isArray(orders) && orders.map((o) => ({ ...o, orderId: String(o.orderId) })) || []
//     ^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                              ^^^^^
```

Нет ни одного ложного значения, на котором `Array.isArray` вернёт true.

Можно было бы подумать, что проверка нужна для сохранения конкретного ложного значения, но нет - в конце cнова `||`.

Этот код без изменения функциональности упрощается до:

```
const orders = await apiQueueService.executeInQueue(this.api.futuresOpenOrders)
return Array.isArray(orders) ? orders.map((o) => ({ ...o, orderId: String(o.orderId) })) : []
```

Но и это фигня потому что:

1. Api должно возвращать ожидаемые данные, а не какой-то мусор. Какие основания полагать, что вместо массива может вернуться что-то другое, но если вернулся массив, то объекты в нём именно того типа, какой ожидается?
2. Если предполагается, что не массив - это ошибка, то её надо нормально обрабатывать, а не заменять данные на пустой массив. Обычно пустой массив является валидным результатом, а значит дальше эти ситуации уже не различить. Лучше бы вообще ошибки различать между собой, но если нет, то даже null был бы полезнее.
3. Преобразование id в строку тоже не радует.

Comment: Спасибо большое! )